# How to bind an object that contains a list of an object from thymeleaf to contoller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf, h2

I'm currently making a recipe application.
Every recipe will be containing several ingredients obviously.
So I made Recipe and Ingredient as OneToMany relationship. So that I can have multiple ingredients in a single recipe.

But the problem is when I try to add recipe using thymeleaf webpage.
I want to add ingredients dynamically, I mean I want to add ingredients as much as I need for each recipe using javascript to make the input boxes for ingredients increase or decrease dynamically.
Here is my Ingredient Entity Class:

```
public class Ingredient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String amount;
}
```

This is Recipe Entity Table

```
public class Recipe {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String instruction;
    private Timestamp createdTime;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

These are methods for adding recipe:

```
@GetMapping("/addRecipe")
public String addRecipeGet(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("recipe", new Recipe());
    return "add_recipe";
}

@PostMapping("/addRecipe")
public String addRecipePost(Recipe recipe) {
    recipeService.createRecipe(recipe);
    return "home";
}
```

And I tried to bind the recipe object with thymeleaf like this:

```html
<body>
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/addRecipe}" th:object="${recipe}" class="form-signup">
    <label class="form-label pt-3" for="name">Recipe Name</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control mb-3" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Recipe Name" />
    <label class="form-label pt-3" for="description">Description</label>
    <textarea id="description" name="description" type="text" class="form-control mb-3" th:field="*{description}" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
    <label class="form-label pt-3" for="instruction">Instruction</label>
    <textarea id="instruction" name="instruction" type="text" class="form-control mb-3" th:field="*{instruction}" placeholder="Instruction"></textarea>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" th:name="???" placeholder="ex) Onion"></input>
                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" th:name="???" placeholder="ex) 300g"></input>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="d-grid col-8 mx-auto">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

I just tried to bind only one ingredient for now but it's not working obviously.. I don't know what to put in the th:field or th:name
I have no idea how to post a list of data inside an object
Is even there a way to solve this problem??

Answer (score 1):

You can bind list items using `th:field="*{ingredients[i].name}"` or name in the same format.

See https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list for a full guide on how to handle list binding in thymeleaf